# Pepper - QiChat: pronunciation of a word in a different language

Tags: pepper

I'd doing an italian dialog on Pepper with qichat language
I have to change the pronunce of a single word (i.e. Engineering) to English. 
What is the qichat instruction that I have to write in the dialog box?
Thanks,
Debora

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options there:

- Try different spellings (e.g. "Ingeniireng", ...) until Peppers pronunciation satisfies your expectations.
- Inserting phonetic text [doc](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-tuto.html?highlight=phonetic#inserting-phonetic-text)